# how to make imageview in gridview link to activity

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-activity

i have a gridview that content some image view, i want from this image view of the grid view can get onclick to change a activity, how can i do it, i try this code but it not work.in main activity a init a grid view and add imageview to it, then i try to create onclick even but it not work

```
gridview.findViewById(R.id.image).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
          startActivity(myIntent);
      }

  });
```

Comment: do you add the Image progreamticly as well?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your ideal

Comment: he's asking: do you create the ImageView by inflating an XML layout or do you create it with Java code, `new ImageVIew(...)` ?

Comment: yes, i created the imageview in xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the click as an item of the GridView, i.e.

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //do whatever you want here...  
        }
    });
```